# Wordpress Nav / Menu onClick event solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Okay, I have a problem:
I have this code that creates a button, but I need that same onClick event in my wordpress menu www.slingerbistro.dk (the top right corner - booking button).

I've read, that it requires to put in some coding in the header.

The booking code I've received is like this:

```
<!-- DinnerBooking Booking Box Start -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.i.dinnerbooking.eu/onlinebooking.js"></script>
<a onclick="return openDBWindow(this.href);" href="http://slingerbistro.b.dinnerbooking.com/onlinebooking/997/2" id="wd_booking_btn" title="Se ledig tid og book bord" class="btn_blue"><span>Se ledig tid og book bord</span></a>
<!-- DinnerBooking Booking Box End -->
```

And what I've done is trying to get that into my header.php in the theme. So far I've come up with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.i.dinnerbooking.eu/onlinebooking.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu-item-top-level-10").on("click", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          // dinnerbooking code here
          return openDBWindow (this.href == "http://slingerbistro.b.dinnerbooking.com/onlinebooking/997/2")
    });
}); </script>
```

Does anybody have the skills to look at my sorry excuse for a code and correct it? I'm not a programmer (obviously) and could really need your help.

The booking button has "#menu-item-top-level-9" so basically the code I'm trying to write should give the same effect with the drop-down-widget as the sample widget I posted on top.

Thank you <3

Comment: Your page does not have id `menu-item-top-level-10` and if it's added dynamically, than do `$(document).on('click', '#menu-item-top-level-10', function)`

Comment: Okay again, I'm not a coder, so could you be so kind to correct the code and paste it for me? And no, it's level-9 - sorry... Maybe there's another way to give the menu-button an ID that can be written in the code - I dont know - that's why I'm asking for your guys help.

Comment: @Justinas `$("#menu-item-top-level-10").on("click", function(e){` is ok, if there is an ID for this.

Comment: Thanks lolka_bolka, but I still need the complete code to work so it will add the onClick event needed (see the widget I received) so it will be a dropdown-lightbox thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.i.dinnerbooking.eu/onlinebooking.js">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#menu-item-362").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // dinnerbooking code here
            return openDBWindow ($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

First, there is no element with id: `menu-item-top-level-10`

Second, you do not want to change the href. You want to read it.

Comment: Didn't work lolka... I found the menu-item-top-level-9 (sorry) in the source code. But it still didn't work...

Comment: Did you copied it exactly? There is no `#menu-item-top-level-9`. `#` means `id`, but `menu-item-top-level-9` is a class. This is why I used `$("#menu-item-362").on .....`

Comment: Let me just check... I might be wrong haha :D Forgive my none-coding-skills :D I'll be back and just check that I've done it correctly

Comment: Okay, I've checked and you are absolutely correct about the ID... Sorry about that!! BUT, it still does not work... I've added a new menu "test" and inserted the correct ID, but it still does not load the dropdown as you can see... 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.i.dinnerbooking.eu/onlinebooking.js">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#menu-item-1543").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // dinnerbooking code here
            return openDBWindow ($(this).attr('href');
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: It says there's an error in the line where it says "return openDBWindow..."

Comment: I see you now added a new `test` menu. Anyway, you code has a missing closing `)`. `return openDBWindow ($(this).attr('href'));` Add a `)` before semicolon.

Comment: Still doesn't work... The error is gone now, thanks, but it still does not load it as it should. If you look here: http://www.slingerbistro.dk/booking/

Click on the green button on the page. That makes the booking widget dropdown. That's the way it should be when you click in the menu as well... That's why I added the embed code I got from the provider (they dont have a fix for this, that's why I'm asking in here)...

Comment: Sorry, nope. I did not see what trigger that on the green button.